Yo quiero crear un usuario, pero no se donde configurar el Dockerfile para ejecutar el script add_user.sh que me permita agregarlo
Deseo crear un usuario en la administracion de Wildfly


Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Para configurar un Dockerfile que ejecute un script add_user.sh para agregar un usuario dentro de un contenedor Docker, puedes seguir estos pasos:
Primero, asegúrate de que tienes el script add_user.sh en el directorio donde estás trabajando con Docker.
Crea un Dockerfile en el mismo directorio con el siguiente contenido:
Dockerfile:
Usa una imagen base de Docker que tenga las herramientas necesarias, como bash, para ejecutar el script
FROM ubuntu:latest
Copia el script add_user.sh al directorio /tmp dentro del contenedor
COPY add_user.sh /tmp/add_user.sh
Ejecuta el script add_user.sh al iniciar el contenedor
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/tmp/add_user.sh"]
Asegúrate de que el script add_user.sh tenga permisos de ejecución. Puedes dar permisos de ejecución al script con el siguiente comando:
bash:
chmod +x add_user.sh
Construye la imagen Docker utilizando el Dockerfile:
bash:
docker build -t nombre_imagen .
Una vez que la imagen se haya construido correctamente, puedes ejecutar un contenedor basado en esa imagen:
bash:
docker run -d --name nombre_contenedor nombre_imagen
Esto ejecutará el script add_user.sh dentro del contenedor al iniciarlo, y deberías ver que se agrega el usuario según lo especificado en el script. Asegúrate de ajustar los nombres de la imagen y el contenedor según tus necesidades.
